git revert to uncommited branch
I forgot to commit changes in a branch and I use checkout.
this is output of git reflog
10b13e2 (origin/main, optimize-step, main, add-step) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from separate-catform to optimize-step
10b13e2 (origin/main, optimize-step, main, add-step) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from optimize-step to separate-catform
10b13e2 (origin/main, optimize-step, main, add-step) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from add-step to optimize-step
10b13e2 (origin/main, optimize-step, main, add-step) HEAD@{4}: commit: change ui

I need to revert all changes to here:
10b13e2 (origin/main, optimize-step, main, add-step) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from optimize-step to separate-catform
Is there any way to get code just before HEAD@{2}

I'm confused, are you sure they're all 10b13e2? Also what do you mean by "uncommitted branch"?

yeah they all is 10b13e2, thats why I can't get the code.

I forgot to commit changes and run 'git checkout separate-catform and git didn't give error that there's uncommited changes and run 'git checkout optimize-step again and code get mess, all existing file revert to old branch but new file is there too.
I don't know what exactly happen.

Which branch do you want the changes on? Have you lost the changes?

something like git reset HEAD@{3} (you can also add --hard) should bring you back to HEAD@{3} so before HEAD@{2} happened

I want optimize-step branch before go to separate-catform.
files that was exist in commit: change ui get reset but I still have new files that wasn't on commit: change ui.

@Hosein don't reset anything if you haven't committed the files

@evolutionxbox without --hard nothing bad should happen: "Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action." git-reset

If you checked out a different branch and not changed anything, simply checkout the previous branch again. Uncommitted changes are not linked to any branch, they live solely in your working tree.

I second knittl's comment. If you want to check your history, don't use git reflog, use git log (here is a variation I almost always use: git log --graph --oneline). You will see that all three branches (including optimize-step) point at the same commit, so you are already in "the same state as before HEAD@{2}".
